# Сделать поле varchar полем date с конвертацией датой в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица `order`. У таблицы есть поле `date` форматом `varchar` (странно да?). Данные записываются в таком виде `25.04.2015`. Как сделать это поле форматом `date` со стандартный форматом записи. `2015-04-25`. При этом все данные переконвертировались?
Может быть сделать дополнительное поле и как то переписать эти данные?

Comment: да, сделать дополнительное поле, переписать данные `STR_TO_DATE`, удалить старое и переименовать, если надо, новое поле в имя старого

Comment: @splash58 средствами php или Mysql?

Comment: mysql - `update thetable set new = STR_TO_DATE(old)` посмотрите в описании функции про форматы. Вы это сделаете в админе за пару минут

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Преобразовать данные можно при помощи следующего запроса

```
UPDATE
  `order`
SET
  `date` = STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%d.%m.%Y');
```

Если помимо формата данных необходим изменить еще и тип столбца `date`, после указанного выше запроса можно выполнить ALTER-запрос

```
ALTER TABLE
  `order`
CHANGE
  `date` `date` DATE NOT NULL;
```